# Single Uppercase letter and seven numerical digits combinations?

Tags: real-analysis

What is the numerical answer to the question: How many possible combinations are there in a single uppercase digit combined with seven numerical digits?

Answer (score 1):

You have 26 options for the uppercase letter.  There are 8 symbols total in the string.  So the letter can be in (8 choose 1)=8 positions.  Therefore, there are $26 \cdot 8$ options for the letter.

For the remaining symbols in the string, you have 7 characters.  Each character has 10 possibilities: 0, 1, 2, ..., 9.  Therefore, there are $10^7$ possibilities for the numerical symbols.

Combining the two together, you have $26\cdot8 \cdot 10^7$ possibilities for the string.

Note: people in the community will often ask you to show an attempt before helping you with a problem.  Just something to keep in mind for the future.  :)